# Tensorflow Object Detection: Detect hands

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, neural-network, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am working on a Gesture Recognition project (end goal: identify the static/dynamic hand gesture under view). I intend to use Neural Networks (Python3, TensorFlow with Keras backend on Jupyter Notebook).

As the first step, to detect hands in images, I followed the [Object Detection Tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) and did whatever was mentioned. I could run the tutorial code successfully on my machine. However, it does not detect hands. I saw many posts online and I know that Hand detection is possible using the same tutorial followed. Moreover, it does mention that in the COCO dataset, one of the categories of classification is "hand" (table #2, second column, fifth row of [Microsoft COCO: Common Objects in Context](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.0312.pdf)).

I don't know what has to be changed. Please guide me regarding this. I did view few online articles, such as [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-real-time-object-recognition-app-with-tensorflow-and-opencv-b7a2b4ebdc32) but found it difficult to follow. I want to find the location of only a hand in any image, and not bothered about other objects.

I am aware of ["Tracking Custom Objects Intro - Tensorflow Object Detection API Tutorial"](https://pythonprogramming.net/custom-objects-tracking-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/), but is the entire process required for hand? Isn't it already trained to detect hands? (as it is mentioned in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.0312.pdf))

Comment: Please comment and let me know if the question above is suitable on this website.

Comment: This more of an open-ended question and might be better for a place like Quora. StackOverflow is for precise programming questions.

Comment: I shared a hand detection tutorial on GitHub. Feel free to check it out: https://github.com/jkjung-avt/hand-detection-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow entire process as described in those articles you listed for any object detection. If you have images of hands, its just few days of work. Follow the video series which you listed its best of all

https://pythonprogramming.net/training-custom-objects-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/